# How to add an allowance plan in Workday

Tags: workday-api

Could someone please let me know how to add a allowance plan for an employee in Workday, so that it will be visible when manager makes a job change in compensation tab.

Manager is trying to add license premium for a new hire, but could not able to find it

1. Login as Manager
2. Search for the employee > Job change
3. Compensation tab > Allowances > Required allowance plan is not there

Please let me know how to check if the new hire is eligible for certain allowance plan, and how to activate this allowance plan for an employee?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below navigations
Related Actions (Action) -> Compensation -> Request Compensation
there you will see all available and configured allowance plans for your tenant.